# How can I set my Ubuntu menu to never have the "Power Off / Log Out" section collapsed?

Tags: power-management, menu, menu-bar

When I click into the menu in the top right corner, I want to see the Power section already expanded like this:

[image: expanded power menu]

...instead of this:

[image: collapsed power menu]